# Getting Specific iOS Device Names from Google Analytics for iOS v2

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I've integrated the Google Analytics for iOS library into my application, and in general it's working.  I see results on the web dashboard, but ... every iPad is reported as "Apple iPad" and that's not specific enough for my needs.

I'd like to be able to override the ga:mobileDeviceModel or ga:mobileDeviceMarketingName with a more specific label like "iPad 3 Retina", "iPad Mini", etc.

My app easily determines which device it is running on, and composes a string like the ones above, but I can't get these to show up in the Google Analytics reporting.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: While the linked question is relevant, I think this question is different as its about putting the above information into GA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution, in my case, was to create a custom dimension on the Google Analytics web interface, which I called MobileDeviceNameSpecific, and then add code to the iOS app to set that custom dimension value in the -viewDidAppear: method of my view controllers, as described in [the documentation on the Google Analytics developer site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/customdimsmets).

Now that I've done that, I can view the devices which have been used by selecting MobileDeviceNameSpecific as a secondary dimension in the Devices report on the Google Analytics web reporting dashboard, which shows the values sent from the iOS app, indicating the specific device in use (e.g. "iPad 3", "iPad Mini").

Comment: What is the scope level do you use for that Custom dimension?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but according to my comment below :) I added it to the user scope.

Comment: Here's the guide for how to setup the Custom Dimension on the web interface. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you are trying to do (I suspect its impossible to fiddle with the built-in features that google reports back to GA), you can use a "Custom Variable" (here's the [js doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)) to report this.  Reporting of custom variables shows up in the same "Audience" section of the standard google reports, so its relatively easy to combine with other "audience" metrics.

Comment: I suspect that you are right. I'm currently trying to add a custom dimension to the user scope. Will report back shortly.